# How to get the Wadler/Leijen pretty printer to render braces on separate lines

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I'm using the [wl-pprint-extras](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint-extras) package. I'm trying to pretty-print LaTeX, improving on [HaTeX](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaTeX-3.16.0.0/docs/Text-LaTeX-Base-Pretty.html), or at least tweaking it to my needs.

An example of the output I'm looking for is:

```
\foo{bar}{
    \baz{\quux}
}{
    \fizz
}
```

and

```
\foo{
    bar
}{
    \baz{\quux}
}{
    \fizz
}
```

I would prefer to avoid, when possible,

```
\foo{
    bar
}{\baz{\quux}}{
    \fizz
}
```

The output that's driving me up a wall is

```
\foo{
    bar
}{\baz{
        \quux
}}{
    \fizz
}
```

The data I have to work with is `TeXComm String [TeXArg]`.

Does anyone have any idea how to get the first and the second while completely avoiding the fourth?

EDIT:

A [gist](https://gist.github.com/rpglover64/6d854500b1f66038dafe) of what I have so far; the two files are the modified pretty printer and some sample LaTeX I'm trying to pretty print.

Comment: What's your code? You can add line breaks with `linebreak` or `hardline`, and increase indentation with `nest`.